# Using drush into remote host is showing me local data

Tags: drush

I have an alias setup for my remote host with the following in the script:

```
<?php
$aliases['lws'] = array(
    'root' => 'domain.com:/home/user/public_html',
    'uri' => 'domain.com',
    'remote-user' => 'user',
);
?>
```

But when I drush using (for example): drush @lws status

I get information back about my local machine and not about the remote machine. I know this is the case because my remote machine is Linux and my local machine is windows...and when I run drush from the remote machine itself it shows me different results than what drush on my local machine is giving me. Also the command above run locally shows me all the alias files I have setup on my local machine (for other drupal installs).

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: Show us the output of `drush sa`

Answer (score 0):

It'd be interesting to see what results you'd get if you modify your script above by removing the `domain.com:` (in 'root'), to make it look like so:

```
<?php
$aliases['lws'] = array(
    'root' => '/home/user/public_html',
    'uri' => 'domain.com',
    'remote-user' => 'user',
);
?>
```

At least that would make it look more like the samples for 'dev' and 'prod' as documented in https://www.drupal.org/node/1401522 .

Curious to hear if this helps somehow ...